# How to re-render the class component except the Text input component - React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a class component with two react components a TextInput and DateTimePicker. I find that when text is in the TextInput and the Datepicker is activated and a date is set the TextInput text gets removed. My assumption is a re-rendering has taken place. My question is how can I set a date without re-rendering the TextInput which removes the text when an input has previously been set. I tried shouldComponentUpdate with useRef but it just stops the entire class component from re-rendering which is not what I would like to achieve.

In nutshell, I would like to rerender my class component but not that specific TextInput when a  date is set. I trust I was clear and would appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Pressable, Keyboard, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import moment from "moment";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import Fontisto from "react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto";
import { TextInput } from "react-native-paper";

class Detail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      iscompletionDateVisible: false,
      completionDate: ""
    };
    this.formRef = React.createRef();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (this.formRef.current.values.miscinfo !== "") {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    const showcompletionDatePicker = () => {
      this.setState({ iscompletionDateVisible: true });
    };
    const handlecompletionDateConfirm = (datetime) => {
      this.setState({
        completionDate: moment(datetime).format("DD/MM/YYYY").toString()
      });
      hidecompletionDateDatePicker();
    };
    const hidecompletionDateDatePicker = () => {
      this.setState({ iscompletionDateVisible: false });
    };

    return (
      <View>
        <Formik
          innerRef={this.formRef}
          enableReinitialize={true}
          initialValues={{
            miscinfo: ""
          }}
          onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
            Keyboard.dismiss();
            // Do submit
          }}
        >
          {(formikprops) => (
            <View>
              <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                <ScrollView>
                  <Text>Misc. Info:</Text>
                  <TextInput
                    name="miscinfo"
                    onChangeText={formikprops.handleChange("miscinfo")}
                    value={formikprops.values.miscinfo}
                  />

                  <Pressable onPress={showcompletionDatePicker}>
                    <Text>Completion Date:</Text>
                    <View style={{ width: "80%" }}>
                      <TextInput
                        pointerEvents="none"
                        value={this.state.completionDate}
                        editable={false}
                        onChangeText={formikprops.handleChange(
                          "completionDate"
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Fontisto
                        style={{ marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 10 }}
                        name="date"
                        size={25}
                        onPress={showcompletionDatePicker}
                      />
                    </View>
                  </Pressable>
                  {this.state.iscompletionDateVisible && (
                    <DateTimePickerModal
                      isVisible={this.state.iscompletionDateVisible}
                      mode="date"
                      onConfirm={handlecompletionDateConfirm}
                      onCancel={hidecompletionDateDatePicker}
                    />
                  )}
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Detail;
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, there is a missing tag around the Pressable element.

Comment: @LukasLaudrain I'm not sure what you think is missing, but can you address the question?

Comment: Could you create a virtual env of the problem so as to recreate the problem ?

Comment: @LukasLaudrain this I can do